# How can I integrate svn with the Visual studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, version-control, integration

How can I integrate svn with the Visual studio 2008 ?

which is the better svn plugin/client for the visual studio ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ is a Visual Studio plugin for svn. I prefer not to plugin directly, but rather to just use svn separately or using TurtoiseSVN ( http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ ) that integrates with explorer, but that's just personal taste I guess.

Comment: I also prefer tortoise over ankh. visual studio always acted just a little wonky with the plugin. the explorer integration just worked.

Answer (score 13):

Couple of utilities.

- [Visual SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/)
- [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)

There are some [comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102324/which-would-you-rather-use-visualsvn-or-ankhsvn) [between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045/ankhsvn-versus-visualsvn) [Visual SVN and Ankh here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252672/ankhsvn-vs-visualsvn).

[Mindscape's file explorer](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/Products/vsfileexplorer/default.aspx) gets you [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) on VS2008, if you are too accustomed to Tortoise

Answer (score 4):

The [Agent SVN](http://zeusedit.com/agent/) is a MS-SCCI plug-in that works *Visual Studio 2008*.

Answer (score 3):

there is [visualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/), [ankhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) or you can (sort of) do it yourself using tools->external tools... (useful if your IT dep are taking ages to approve the others)